# Is it possible to use authentication by OIDC and provisioning of users/groups by SCIM at the same time?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, scim

I have a question about Azure Active Directory.

Is it possible to use authentication by OIDC and provisioning of users/groups by SCIM at the same time?

We are developing a scratch application and would like to use Open ID Connect for authentication, but we would like to store user/group information within the application and would like to use SCIM provisioning to solve this issue. We wanted to solve this problem by provisioning with SCIM.

However, it appears that if we want to use SCIM provisioning, we need to register our own application as an enterprise application.

On the other hand, if I register it as an enterprise application, I can't seem to use OIDC as a single sign-on method.

Based on the above, it seems to me that OIDC and SCIM cannot be used together, is that correct?

Regards,
Keiichi Hikita

- I wanted to register my own application as an enterprise application, so I chose to register an enterprise application
- Select SSO method
- Only SAML is shown
- Register as just an application
- Authentication with OIDC seems to work.
- But this time, I can't register provisioning settings by SCIM in the provisioning menu.

These are the reasons for the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create two applications - one for OIDC-based SSO, and a second one that is marked as SAML but does not have any SAML/SSO configured, but instead is just used for the SCIM provisioning configuration.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

It sounds like a good idea to make two applications.
I believe it works !!